# How to import table as external table using sqoop

Tags: hive, sqoop

Is there anyway that we can import the table as external table in Hive using sqoop command?

Thanks
Piyush Jindal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no native support for external tables in Sqoop. There is already a JIRA for it thought:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-816

Comment: Thanks @Jarek
After going thru the jira, i have found that we can do the same using the given below commands :-
ALTER TABLE <Tablename> SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='TRUE');